# How many lumens from 1 gram of flash powder

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Does somebody know how many lumens we get from lighting 1 gram of flash powder in pure oxygen (or normal) environment? I'm thinking about $\ce{KClO_4} $ (60%) + $\ce{Al}$ (40%)  flash powder and quite fast flaming due to lighting it up with electricity.